# Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 — why?

Tags: java, arrays, private-constructor

This code works:

```
class Test {
    static int size;
}

public class E08_ConnectionApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Test[] test = new Test[Test.size];
        for (int i = 0; i < Test.size; i++) test[i] = new Test();
    }
}
```

But when I do **THE SAME** for other classes, I get the error from the title. I don't understand what's wrong. Please, tell me.

This code doesn't work:

```
class Connection {
    private int ID;

    private Connection(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;

        print("Connection number " + ID + " created.");
    }

    static Connection createNewConnection(int ID) { return new Connection(ID); }

    Connection getConnection() { return this; }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
}
class ConnectionManager {
    private int size;

    public ConnectionManager(int size) {
        this.size = size;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) connections[i] = Connection.createNewConnection(i + 1);
    }

    private Connection[] connections = new Connection[size];

    public Connection getAvailableConnection() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (connections[i] != null) {
                Connection temp = connections[i].getConnection();
                connections[i] = null;
                print("Connection #" + temp.getID() + " fetched.");
                return temp;
            }

        print("No connections available...");
        return null;
    }
}

public class E08_ConnectionApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
}
```

When debugging, I get an error from the title in this line:

`for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) connections[i] = Connection.createNewConnection(i + 1);`

I'm 95% sure that this error is because `connections`, although has space allocated for it (an array of size 5, which is an argument of the program), contains `null` references to `Connection` objects. But what I'm trying to do is actually initialize this array, to attach array references to actual objects. If I'm doing it wrong, what is the right way?

I'm thinking about some bad settings in my project or maybe IntelliJ IDEA bug, but the latter is *highly unlikely*.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

I tried google the error and thinking for myself, I tried various ways to reproduce the problem, but in `Test` everything works as expected...

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the argument to the second class' `main` correctly? If you don't the `args` will be empty and getting the first element `[0]` will throw that error.

Comment: "I'm 95% sure that this error is because connections ...": If you want to be 100% sure, look at the stack trace. It'll tell you exactly on which line the error occurs. My guess would be it's the `main` function itself, not the `ConnectionManager`.

Comment: Where does `size` come from in `new Connection[size]`? The size of your array seems not to be related to the one passed to the `ConnectionManager` constructor.

Comment: Your `Connection#getConnection` method is a little silly. Outside that, the idea of making the array elements null in order to retrieve sole access to a connection is a bit misplaced: this is not thread-safe code, and it's boilerplate for single-threaded.

Comment: Is this an exercise you're doing or a real connection pool?

Comment: @Ivar `size` is a field of `ConnectionManager`. Do you want to tell space allocation for `connections` happens before calling the constructor? But then the compiler would have produced an error, wouldn't it?



@Jorn I'm sure, moreover, if I substitute `args[0]` for a literal, it also doesn't work.

Comment: It is definitely **not** the same. In example 1 you're creating the `Test` array after you got the size input. In example 2 you're creating the array **before** you set the size via the constructor.

Comment: @g00se This is an exercise from TiJ4. 

Hello, g00se, BTW. I remember you from different question.

Comment: Correct, your `connections` field is initialized before the constructor is called. So you have a zero-sized `connections` array, which then fails on `connections[0]` in the constructor.

Comment: @QBrute So I suggested right? Field initialization happens **before** the constructor? And that's the problem? 

OH, YES, MAN, YES!!! I just put array initialization in the constructor after assigning `size`. Now it works!

Order of initialization, yeah, one should know it. Sorry for an ignorant question...

Thank you guys!!!

Comment: Somebody may post your comment as an answer. I'll accept, and you'll get some points.

Comment: What I don't get now is why it is so. There's no object before the constructor. And how you can initialize a field of an object before it's created (via constructor call)?!

Comment: @Нормальныйдневник No you are wrong: the object is created, it is just not fully initialized before finishing constructor

Comment: @AdrianShum Maybe fields are implicitly initialized in the beginning of a constructor, before its first explicit line...

Comment: @Нормальныйдневник yup. There are other initialization works happens outside your explicitly-written constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply because the array was created before your constructor:

```
class ConnectionManager {
    private int size;

    // you tried to create array with size, for which is not initialised yet, 
    // which is 0 for int instance variable
    private Connection[] connections = new Connection[size];  


    public ConnectionManager(int size) {
        this.size = size;  // this assignment happens after your array creation
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) connections[i] = Connection.createNewConnection(i + 1);
    }
```

(Rearranged the code slightly)

Those initialisation statements (e.g. `private Connection[] connections = new Connection[size];`) are performed before your Constructor logic.  Which means, when it tried to create the `connections` array, `size` is still 0, hence the array is created with 0 size.

The proper way is

```
class ConnectionManager {
    private int size;
    private Connection[] connections;


    public ConnectionManager(int size) {
        this.size = size;  // this is actually superfluous. 
                           // You can always get it directly from array's size
        this.connections = new Connection[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) connections[i] = Connection.createNewConnection(i + 1);
    }
```

Comment: a bit off topic: I suggest OP to pay more attention to coding style etc.  If these code are arranged in a more readable way as above, problem could be spotted earlier and easier.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening in the latter 2 classes because they have constructors but doesn't occur on `Test` because it doesn't have a constuctor.

What this shows is that `arg[0]` is actually null or undefined, but it doesn't matter with `Test` as this value isn't actually being used in the constructor.  In the latter 2 classes, the constructors are trying to assign null or undefined to a primitive `int` rather than an `Integer`, which can't be null, thus producing the error.  As `arg[0]` is null or undefined, this shows that the app is actually being run without arguments.  The only other problem may be if `arg[0]` is a string which can't be parsed as a number, but I'm pretty confident this would give you a parsing exception.

Please try running the app with an extra argument that can be parsed to an integer and see if the error still persists.  This will tell you for sure if this is the case.  Furthermore, you should add a constructor to `Test` to confirm this is the problem, as `Test` should throw the same exception if it has a constructor and this is indeed the correct error.

Answer (score 0):

For a zero length array, no index value is valid.

This is no index 1, no index 0, no index *anything*.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < Test.size; i++) test[i] = new Test();
```

This test doesn't throw because it iterates all the valid indecies of the test array, from zero to size-1. If size is zero the loop never runs.